# RESTful webservice doesn't start on Tomcat 8.0.5

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I wrote a simple webservice that parses an XMLfile with JAXB. This service works when I 'Run' it from the menu of NetBeans(Tomcat 8.0.3), But if I put the WAR file into webapps folder of tomcat and start tomcat(server.xml is identical between the two servers), I get the following error:

Please help resolve this:

```
01-Sep-2015 15:07:45.979 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.006 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.009 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.277 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.280 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.283 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.283 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 824 ms
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.5
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.356 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.5-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\k4kReadOrderService.war
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.372 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
01-Sep-2015 15:07:46.972 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers Failed to process JAR found at URL [/k4kReadOrderService] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [{1}]
 java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1125)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5058)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1762)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:182)
    ... 19 more

01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.006 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.015 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error getConfigured
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.017 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/k4kReadOrderService] startup failed due to previous errors
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.027 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.5-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\docs
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.142 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.5-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\examples
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.604 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.5-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\host-manager
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.647 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.5-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\manager
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.698 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.5-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\ROOT
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.726 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.732 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.734 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
01-Sep-2015 15:07:47.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1452 ms
```

Comment: HTTPS is not the issue, if I remove the https config, the other error still persists. I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your **servlet-api** is included several times with:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

If so, you can exclude transitional dependencies in one of them using (example of how I fixed same problem):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```